# VBA's double object type with length > 1

Tags: vba, double

Where can I find information on `doubles` that contain more than 1 number?

For example

```
Option Explicit

Private d(2) as Double
```

Then `d(1)` and `d(2)` are now two different doubles apparently.

I can't find any information of this on Google? I want to read about this object type...

Comment: ... and `d(0)` will be a third double. You may find it useful to read up on the `Dim` and `ReDim` and `Option Base` statements.

Comment: See this link for a better understanding of arrays http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164778%28v=office.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an *array* of doubles so I'd be looking up `vba array` for a start.

It's not limited to doubles, you have have arrays of a great many data types.

Comment: @Harokitty: no problems, I'm old, both here on SO, _and_ in life :-)